# Arabic: reading of numbers (starts from most or least significant digit)?

Tags: arabic

On discussion on computer representions of numbers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185551/why-is-x86-little-endian/36263273#36263273 I've read a comment

> Arabic is written from right to left, which might explain the
>   orientation of our numbering system: for them, it is indeed little
>   endian!

and then I wanted to check that.

Just to be clear what is meant: number 123 is read 3 then 2 then 1.

Indeed google translate translates numbers to Arabic the same as originals (and I know general text is read from right to left), but Arabic calculators (found via search for `online calculator` translated by google to آلة حاسبة على الانترنت (online https://a-calc.info/scientific.html and youtube videos I've watched) shows numbers are entered starting with most significant digit. I'm confused therefore.

Do Arabs (usually, in modern life) read numbers starting from least significant digit and just there are no calculators adjusted to their way of life?

ADDED: I could not find more info cause I searched for `Arabic` and numbers are arabic anyway, now I've searched for `Arab read` and found couple of answers:

https://www.quora.com/Why-are-numerals-written-left-to-right-in-Arabic

https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294205-i9426-k2996990-Arabic_numbers_Which_way_round-Luxor_Nile_River_Valley.html

1. Looks like now in modern life Arabs read numbers `English` way
   mostly and no need for special calculators?
2. If read traditional way, how you read e.g. 51 234 (you say `thousands` before `1`)?

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE! Unfortunately questions about specific features of languages are off topic here. You could, instead, ask how to learn which the numbers are read. Maybe say a few words about what you already know about the language - can you speak or read it at all?

Comment: @Tommi, thank you for advice, but I do not completely understood meaning of "ask how to learn which the numbers are read. ". Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should be: "in which order numbers are read".

Comment: Hi Marisha, I have closed your question, since this site is about learning (or teaching) languages (i.e. how to do that, what resources are available etc) but not about how specific aspects of a language work. If you can reword your question, e.g. about how to learn how order numbers work, then it may get reopened.